# Issue with Lambda function for custom resource: No module named cfnresponse

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I'm attempting to create a CloudFormation custom resource using a Lambda function. This is my function:

```
    "SubnetToVpcFunction": {
        "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
        "Properties": {
            "Code": {
                "ZipFile" : { "Fn::Join" : ["\n", [
                    "import cfnresponse",
                    "import json, boto3 ",
                    "def handler(event, context): ",
                    "   ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2') ",
                    "   subnet = ec2.Subnet(event['ResourceProperties']['Subnet']) ",
                    "   vpc_id = subnet.vpc_id ",
                    "   responsedata = { 'VPCID' : vpc_id } ",
                    "   cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, responseData, \"CustomResourcePhysicalID\") "
                ] ] }
            },
            "Handler": "index.handler",
            "Runtime": "python2.7",
            "Timeout": "30",
            "Role": { "Fn::Join" : [ "", [ "arn:aws:iam::", { "Ref" : "AWS::AccountId" }, ":role/", { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "AccountMapping", { "Ref" : "AWS::AccountId" }, "Role" ] } ] ] },
        }
    }
```

When I attempt to use this function for a custom resource in another template, the custom resource fails to stabilize, and I see this error in the CloudWatch logs for the function:

```
Unable to import module 'index': No module named cfnresponse
```

According to the AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-code.html#cfn-lambda-function-code-cfnresponsemodule), the `cfnresponse` python package is available for importing in Lambda functions when the function code is specified inline using the `ZipFile` property. So why can't it load the package?

Comment: Answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49885302/1013183

Answer (score 1):

I did use terraform to deploy the lambda function and had to embed the module myself. Either get it from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cfn-response, using pip and virtualenv or using the file attached to the AWS documentation you mentioned.

The documentation suggest, that if you use cloudformation *and* inline code (as ZipFile) but I didn't test that.

Comment: Well, if I have to embed the module myself, then I can't define the function inline in the CFT (because I'd have to manually build the function package with the dependency included.) The main benefit I get from defining the function inline is not having to worry about building/deploying the function package. Thanks for your comment!