# AWS CloudFormation event hanging in CREATE_IN_PROGRESS state after custom resource (lambda) invocation

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have a lambda that has a python script to create an application.properties file in parameter store. I have a cloudformation template that invokes this lambda to create application.properties. My cloudformation template looks like:

```
{
   "Description": "Create SSM Parameter",
   "Resources": {
      "primerinvoke": {
         "Type": "AWS::CloudFormation::CustomResource",
         "Properties": {
            "Handler": "lambda_function.lambda_handler",
            "ServiceToken": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:1234:function:test_lambda",
            "FunctionName": "test_lambda"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

My python script to create SSM parameter (whose path is: /myapp/dev/test/application.properties) is:

```
import boto3
import os

region = os.environ['AWS_REGION']
client = boto3.client('ssm')
def ssm_create():
    response = client.put_parameter(Name='/myapp/'
                                    + os.environ['environment']
                                    + '/test/application.properties',
                                    Description='string',
                                    Value='APPLICATION_NAME=myapp',
                                    Type='SecureString', Overwrite=True)
    return response
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    PutParameterResult = ssm_create()
```

I used `import cfnresponse` as suggested in [AWS lambda: No module named 'cfnresponse'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49885243/aws-lambda-no-module-named-cfnresponse), however, the import doesn't work and I don't know how to install cfnresponse library externally on the lambda.

The code runs successfully which means that cloudformation template was able to invoke the lambda & it's script and create the SSM parameter but it hangs after `ssm_create()` function in my script completes. I don't know how to return a status of "SUCCESS" from my script to the cloudformation stack to prevent it from hanging in `CREATE_IN_PROGRESS` state.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

**EDIT1:** I updated my code to:

```
responseStatus = 'SUCCESS'
responseBody={}
def sendResponse(event, context, responseStatus):
            responseBody = {'Status': responseStatus,
                            'Reason': 'See the details in CloudWatch Log Stream: ' + context.log_stream_name,
                            'PhysicalResourceId': context.log_stream_name,
                            'StackId': event['StackId'],
                            'RequestId': event['RequestId'],
                            'LogicalResourceId': event['LogicalResourceId'],
                            }
            print 'RESPONSE BODY:n' + json.dumps(responseBody)
def lambda_handler(event, context):
                logger.info(event)
                test_ssm_create()
                try:
                    req = requests.put(event['ResponseURL'], data=json.dumps(sendResponse(event, context, responseStatus)))
                    if req.status_code != 200:
                        print req.text
                        raise Exception('Recieved non 200 response while sending response to CFN.')
                except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
                    print e
                    raise
                return
                print("COMPLETE")
```

The `req.status_code` is giving 200 but the cloudformation stack is again getting stuck at CREATE_IN_PROGRESS. Still not sure how to make this work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in the CloudFormation documentation, CloudFormation expects your Lambda function to callback to it once it has completed its operation; CloudFormation will pause execution until this callback is received.  The event sent to your Lambda function by CloudFormation contains the callback URL (ResponseURL) as shown in this example:

```
{
   "RequestType" : "Create",
   "ResponseURL" : "http://pre-signed-S3-url-for-response",
   "StackId" : "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:123456789012:stack/stack-name/guid",
   "RequestId" : "unique id for this create request",
   "ResourceType" : "Custom::TestResource",
   "LogicalResourceId" : "MyTestResource",
   "ResourceProperties" : {
      "Name" : "Value",
      "List" : [ "1", "2", "3" ]
   }
}
```

If you are not able to import the cfnresponse module, which seems to be python2 code, you should be able to simulate the same with python3.  Try adding something like this code in your lambda_handler function.  Note that you there are required keys in the response that are detailed in [this AWS documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/crpg-ref-responses.html) (i.e. PhysicalResourceId, StackId, RequestId, LogicalResourceId  that are straightforward to add, see the documentation).

```
import requests
import json
import uuid

status = {'Status': 'SUCCESS',
          'PhysicalResourceId': 'MyResource_' + str(uuid.uuid1()),
          'StackId': event['StackId'],
          'RequestId': event['RequestId'],
          'LogicalResourceId': event['LogicalResourceId']
         }
r = requests.put(event['ResponseURL'], data=json.dumps(status))
```

So to edit the code in your question:

```
responseStatus = 'SUCCESS'

def getResponse(event, context, responseStatus):
            responseBody = {'Status': responseStatus,
                            'PhysicalResourceId': context.log_stream_name,
                            'StackId': event['StackId'],
                            'RequestId': event['RequestId'],
                            'LogicalResourceId': event['LogicalResourceId'],
                            }
            responseBody = json.dumps(responseBody)
            print 'RESPONSE BODY:n' + responseBody

            return responseBody

def lambda_handler(event, context):
                logger.info(event)
                test_ssm_create()
                try:
                    req = requests.put(event['ResponseURL'], data=getResponse(event, context, responseStatus))
                    if req.status_code != 200:
                        print req.text
                        raise Exception('Received non 200 response while sending response to CFN.')
                except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
                    print e
                    raise
                return
                print("COMPLETE")
```

Comment: The stack moved forward from `CREATE_IN _PROGRESS` to `CREATE_FAILED` where it gives an error saying Invalid PhysicalResourceId. I tried this solution link by giving `r.PhysicalResourceID = context.LogStreamName` but not sure how to give it to the cloudformation stack. Please let me know.

Comment: @nikitakakra Looks like I missed some required fields in the response.  This should be straightforward to fix. Look here and when I get in front of my computer I’ll edit my answer.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/crpg-ref-responses.html

Comment: I followed the documentation you shared but the stack is still getting stuck. Can you see my EDIT in the post with the new code that I've written? I might be doing something wrong there but not sure what it is

Comment: @nikitakakra I think the issue you have is with variable scope, I'm posting an update to my answer based on your latest code.

Comment: @nikitakakra Awesome, please don't forget to accept the answer.